# MySQL column used to sort - auto increment

Tags: mysql

I have a table with primary id auto generated and a separate order column (integer which might be changed by a GUI application). I would like the `order` column to be auto incremented when new row is inserted. It can be the same value as new `car_id`, I don't care. Is it possible?

I think I can have more then one auto increment fields, but they both need to be part of the primary key, and to prevent to potentially have two cars with same `car_id` I would need unique index on `car_id`? Am I correct?

I think I can use triggers, but they are prohibited by my hosting company.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `car` (
  `car_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Why I would like it to be handled by the database is because I use a complicated system of database handling in my program (using generic types and reflection to make everything automated) and this feature would make my life easier.

Comment: `order`? Noooooooooooooooo

Comment: I translated the actual column name, it's actually different (did not think it matters).

Comment: See documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html ... `There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT column per table ... ` and also; `For MyISAM tables, you can specify an AUTO_INCREMENT secondary column in a multiple-column key.` It means, that it is not possible for InoDB tables. The only option is to use triggers.